"Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop", I don't understand how to do it
Hi so I have an assignment from my school, it has something to do with data fetching from randomuser.me and as I have followed the steps that were taught, I stumbled upon this sentence written on the terminal. The project was compiled and running but the warning has been popping up. I'm learning node.js and using typescript and Daisy UI plugins. What I'm trying to do here is to get the data from the api and map it in a card-looking container. As I said the compiling process and the result expected were ok but the warning keeps popping up I'm not sure where I went wrong. I'm new to this so I'm open to corrections. Here's the code:
"use client"

import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Image from "next/image"



export default function TeamCards() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<any[]>([])

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20&inc=name,email,picture&noinfo&nat=GE')
            const data = await res.json()
            setUser(data.results)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);

        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

    const expertise : string[] = [
        "CEO", "CFO", "COO", "Marketing Specialist", "Chief Marketing Officer",
        "Human Resources", "Production Manager", "Sales Representative", "Chief Marketing Officer", "Business Analyst",
        "Financial Analyst", "Project Manager", "Agribusiness Manager", "Agricultural Advisor", "Agronomy Manager",
        "Agricultural Technologist", "Procurement Manager", "Soil Scientist", "Food Scientist", "Irrigation Specialist"
    ]

    return (
            <div >
                {user.map((item, idx) => (
                    <div className="inline-flex p-7">
                        <div key={idx} className="card card-compact bg-green-950 w-[280px] text-white shadow-xl">
                            <figure>
                                <Image src={item.picture.large} width={280} height={280} alt=""/>
                            </figure>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h2 className="card-title">{item.name.first} { item.name.last}</h2>
                                <p className="font-bold underline">{expertise[idx]}</p>
                                <p>Contact:</p>
                                <p>{item.email}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
    )
}

I've tried moving the key property to different divs but it didn't work. I've also tried not to use index as the key props but I used the key={item.id.value} and it still didn't work

"I've tried moving the key property to different divs but it didn't work" - it should be on the <div className="inline-flex p-7">. "I've also tried not to use index as the key props but I used the key={item.id.value}" - there is no .id.value in the items the api returns. Try using item.email instead (on the assumption that it is unique)

You should apply 'key' to the top-level element within the map function.
{user.map((item, idx) => (
  <div className="inline-flex p-7" key={idx}>

